# how to make local images working in webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have created a library that has some UI components. There is a component that takes an image source to show the image.

Now I have created a project in which I have consumed this library. This project uses `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` to serve the files. For image support, I have added like this in **webpack-config.js**

```
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

Here is the component in the library that takes image source

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-compo",
    templateUrl: "my-compo.html"
})
export class MyCompo {
    @Input()
    imageSource: any;
}
```

and the markup of this component

```
<div style="margin:5px">
    <img [src]="imageSource">
</div>
```

And this is how I am using in the project

```
<my-compo [imageSource]="imageUrl"></my-compo>
```

`imageUrl` is

```
imageUrl: "../../assets/images/AssetPreview.png";
```

and when the component is rendered on the screen

```
<div style="margin:5px"><img alt="Asset" src="../../images/img1.png"></div>
```

but this shows `404` http error code that

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/img1.png
```

not found.

How can I solve this?

**Update**

On the project side, I am also using the logo that is an SVG image. And the URL I am providing is

```
<img src="../../assets/images/logo.svg">
```

when I see this in the browser it is rendered as

```
<img src="d91e51aeba7c150154372f81062efb9a.svg">
```

but in case of library component, it is rendering the

```
<img alt="Asset" src="../../assets/images/AssetPreview.png">
```

I guess `webpack-dev-server` is not solving the image url in this case.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/assets/images/img1.png as your image is placed in assets folder

Comment: Check http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server and you will see all the available URLs

Answer (score 0):

`fil-loader` module change the path and name of files. So in my case, as image `src` was binded through a variable then it was not getting resolved. So I have to provide some option with the `file-loader` module

```
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|jpe?g|png|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]" }
```

I have specified the `name` of the file that **Configure a custom filename template for your file**

Here is the full detail on [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)